# ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e7d' The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm getting this error and I can't really find a solution..
I'm not sql expert, Somebody told me the syntax is not correct, is that right?

```
ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e7d' 
The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context. 
/SelectBanner.inc, line 9
```

SelectBanner.inc inside:

```
<%
    sql5 = "SELECT * " &_
            "FROM Banners " &_
            "WHERE BannerNum="&thelocation&" AND TheLanguage='hebrew'"

    Set BannersRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    BannersRS.Open sql5, conn, 3, 1

    TotalRecords = 0

    DO WHILE not (BannersRS.eof)
        TotalRecords=TotalRecords+1
        BannersRS.MoveNext
    LOOP

    If (not(BannersRS.bof)) Then
        BannersRS.MoveFirst
    End If

    rndMax = TotalRecords

    x=0
%>
```

This is the "connection.asp" file:

```
<!--#include file=security.asp--> 
<% 
    set conn = server.createobject("ADODB.connection") 'the next code needed for times when the connection is included from other places than /httpdocs/ 
    ar = Split(server.mappath("."),"\") 
    NewPath = ar(0) 'get the c:\ 
    If ar(index) = "httpdocs" Then 
        index = UBound(ar) 
    Next 
    NewPath = NewPath&"\Data\xxxxxx.mdb" 
    conn.connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="&NewPath&";Persist Security Info=False" 
    conn.open() 
    set rs = conn.execute("select * from siteInfo") 
    taxValue = rs("tax") 
    set rs = nothing 
%>
```

Comment: Where is `conn`  in `BannersRS.Open sql5, conn, 3, 1
`defined?

Comment: This is the "connection.asp" file:
`<!--#include file=security.asp-->
<%
 set conn = server.createobject("ADODB.connection")

'the next code needed for times when the connection is included from other places than /httpdocs/ 
 ar=Split(server.mappath("."),"\")
 NewPath=ar(0) 'get the c:\
  If ar(index)="httpdocs" Then index=UBound(ar)
 Next
 NewPath=NewPath&"\Data\xxxxxx.mdb"
 conn.connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="&NewPath&";Persist Security Info=False"
 conn.open()
 set rs = conn.execute("select * from siteInfo")
 taxValue = rs("tax")
 set rs = nothing
%>`

Comment: @shlomi, I have added the comment in the OP. Why is there a `Next` where it should be an `End If`?

Comment: I reckon execute should be open http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308611